# matlab : working with strings

Tags: string, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with string elements

```
A = [ Jack Sara Bob]
B = [0 0 0 0 0 0 
     0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

And wanted to put A elements in B like: B(2,3:6)=A
But it doesn't work. can anybody help?

Comment: What error message do you get?  It looks like you're trying to put entire strings into a double, which won't work.  Probably you need a cell array.

Comment: Why aren't you enclosing strings with apostrophes (`''`)? Why are you trying to store variable-length strings in a matrix instead of a cell array?

Comment: So what result do you want exactly? Do you want `B = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 Jack Sara Bob ]` ?

Comment: Put your desired output. This question isn't answerable without it. Also note that 3:6 is **4** elements where A only has **3**, unless its a character array, in which case it has **12**. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Because they don't have the same length. B(2,3:6) is length-4 while A is longer than 10. What A really contains is characters rather than strings/words.